# How to add a Class that extends FlutterPlugin to GeneratedPluginRegistrant?

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart

I have my class that extends FlutterPlugin and MethodCallHandler. I would like to add this to the GeneratedPluginRegistrant. If i add it manually, fultter run is going to overwrite the list. What is the solution here? (Its not a flutter package, just a Class in the native android project)

Comment: see https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/plugin-api-migration

Comment: Thx, iam not sure what is the useful information here. Could you please tell me what sould i do? What is more i did not create a new flutter package, i just added the class to the native android project.

Comment: Can you please help me?